# Is this enum/trait a good way to implement polymorphic design in Rust?

Tags: coding-style, coding-standards, rust

this is my first post on here, and I'm wondering about a good rust implementation with traits on enum types.  I want to know if using an enum w/ a trait as a generator of different code is viable like the one below?  Also a couple of things I'm curious about is if there is an overhead with the match statement?  Would implementing separate structs be faster?

```rust
struct GeneralCell {
    repr: char,
    position: Position,
    cell_type: Cell,
}

trait InitializeCells {
    fn new(&self, position: Position) -> GeneralCell;
}

pub enum Cell {
    Hall,
    Filled,
    Empty,
}

impl InitializeCells for Cell {
    fn new(&self, position: Position) -> GeneralCell {
        match self {
            Cell::Hall => GeneralCell {
                repr: 'H',
                position,
                cell_type: Cell::Hall,
            },
            Cell::Empty => GeneralCell {
                repr: 'E',
                position,
                cell_type: Cell::Empty,
            },
            Cell::Filled => GeneralCell {
                repr: 'F',
                position,
                cell_type: Cell::Filled,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this be used? What are the design goals? Why are you introducing a trait when you could `impl` the method directly? Note that design-level questions are on-topic here, but if you're more interested in code-level help. [so] would be the better address.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I think you answered my question(partially).  So this is more of a toy example of me trying the best way to learn the language with code re-usability(as I'm still a Rust noob).  I didn't know if traits were used like this.  I'm trying to create a randomly generated dungeon, with a variable amount of different cell types.  If I create many different types(like 50+), would matching be the best way to go about it(with one struct to hold all the general info).  What would be the best way to bind specific cell behaviors.  More matching?

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two ways I would consider implementing this:

## Using an enum

This is usually the appropriate design, in particular when you know all possible types up front. A benefit is the strong type checking, as you will be warned if a `match` forgets to handle a particular type.

```rust
pub enum Cell {
    Hall,
    Filled,
    Empty,
}

impl Cell {
    pub fn get_char(&self) -> char {
        match self {
            Self::Hall => 'H',
            Self::Filled => 'F',
            Self::Empty => 'E',
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eff909882165138262a103e5d075f1f1</sup>

## Using a trait

This is a more flexible design, and allows you to more easily add new cell types later. You can also more easily add custom behaviour to cells. However, you now have to use trait objects, e.g. by storing the cell type as `Box<dyn Cell>`.

```rust
pub trait Cell {
    // If the char only depends on the type of cell, you can remove the `&self`.
    fn get_char(&self) -> char;
}

struct Hall;

impl Cell for Hall {
    fn get_char(&self) -> char {
        'H'
    }
}

struct Filled;

impl Cell for Filled {
    fn get_char(&self) -> char {
        'F'
    }
}

struct Empty;

impl Cell for Empty {
    fn get_char(&self) -> char {
        'E'
    }
}
```

<sup>Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c5fdd7e1669814f3db04eacd9f43fa1b</sup>